# Azure: Cannot specify storage account while creating a new UN - managed disk for azure.

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-java-sdk

I am trying to create and attach an unmanaged storage disk to Azure. I am unable to specify the storage account while creating the disk.

```
vm.update().defineUnmanagedDataDisk(diskLabel)
                    .withNewVhd(lun)
                    .withLun(lun)
                    .withCaching(CachingTypes.NONE)
                    .attach()
                    .apply();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-premium-storage):

> In an unmanaged disk, you manage the storage accounts that you use to
>   store the virtual hard disk (VHD) files that correspond to your VM
>   disks. VHD files are stored as page blobs in Azure storage accounts.

You can follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-create-vm-specialized#upload-the-vm-vhd-to-your-storage-account) to upload VHD file to your Storage Account,then use  `.storeAt(storageAccount.name(), "diskvhds", "datadisk1vhd.vhd")` to specify the storage account.Please refer to the source code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/c585f414a5e4e62b4ce5d51afd1d4a06a0e49d68/azure-mgmt-compute/src/test/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperationsTests.java#L294).

```
 VirtualMachine virtualMachine = computeManager.virtualMachines()
                .define(VMNAME)
                .withRegion(REGION)
                .withExistingResourceGroup(RG_NAME)
                .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
                .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
                .withoutPrimaryPublicIPAddress()
                .withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UBUNTU_SERVER_16_04_LTS)
                .withRootUsername("Foo12")
                .withRootPassword("abc!@#F0orL")
                .withUnmanagedDisks()
                .defineUnmanagedDataDisk("disk1")
                    .withNewVhd(100)
                    .withLun(2)
                    .storeAt(storageAccount.name(), "diskvhds", "datadisk1vhd.vhd")
                    .attach()
                .defineUnmanagedDataDisk("disk2")
                    .withNewVhd(100)
                    .withLun(3)
                    .storeAt(storageAccount.name(), "diskvhds", "datadisk2vhd.vhd")
                    .attach()
                .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_DS2_V2)
                .withOSDiskCaching(CachingTypes.READ_WRITE)
                .create();
```

Note that 
  `.storeAt(storageAccount.name(), "diskvhds", "datadisk1vhd.vhd")`

means `.storeAt(<your account name>, <container name>, <blob name>)`

Answer (score 0):

The root reason is **Azure does not support attach unmanaged disk to a VM that uses managed disk.**

If your VM uses managed disks, you can only attach additional managed data disks. Also, you can only attach unmanaged data disks to a VM that uses unmanaged disks in a storage account. In other words, Azure does not support attach managed disk and unmanaged disk to a VM at same time.